# Blazor - Losing connection when selecting large amount of files with <InputFile>

Tags: blazor-server-side

The `<InputFile>` component works just fine up to a certain point. When I select (let's say 300 files), Chrome (or Edge) is losing connection. Any ideas?

`<InputFile OnChange="@OnDrawingChange" multiple/>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAOO6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the Program.cs file, this did the trick for me:

```
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => { options.MaxRequestBodySize = 104857600; });
builder.Services.AddSignalR(opt => opt.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000);
```